# Order an array by closest values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'd like to find an algorithm to order by closest value. I think an example would clarify what i'm saying :

Let say we have an array like this :
`var arr = [10,45,69,72,80];` and `var num = 73;`

What i would like is a function that returns this array like this.

```
function orderByClosest(arr, num){
  //enter code here
  return arr; //and arr = [72,69,80,45,10]
}
```

Hope i'm clear enough.

Thanks.

Comment: What should happen if `var num = 40`

Comment: For `var num = 40`, it would output `[45,69,10,72,80]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) with [`Math.abs()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs).

```
arr.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(a - num) - Math.abs(b - num));
```

Using ES5 Syntax for older browsers

```
arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return Math.abs(a - num) - Math.abs(b - num);
});
```

To consider negative numbers too, don't use `Math.abs()`.

```js
var arr = [10, 45, 69, 72, 80];
var num = 73;

var result = arr.sort((a, b) => Math.abs(a - num) - Math.abs(b - num));;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For greater amount of data, I suggest to use [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map).

```js
function orderByClosest(list, num) {
    // temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
    var mapped = list.map(function (el, i) {
        return { index: i, value: Math.abs(el - num) };
    });

    // sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
    mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.value - b.value;
    });

    // return the resulting order
    return mapped.map(function (el) {
        return list[el.index];
    });
}

console.log(orderByClosest([72, 69, 80, 45, 10], 73));
console.log(orderByClosest([72, 69, 80, 45, 10], 40));
```